# SharePoint 2010 Development with Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My company has SharePoint server farm setup and run on internet and local. Now we have to develop some application on it.
How can we do that from VS2010 on PC/Laptop (which does not have SharePoint server installed)?
If we have to remote connect to server and use VS 2010 on server, how can multiple people can work at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can develop SharePoint applications without SP installed but will be limited to using the REST Api, ClientContext API or an external connector like [Camelot .NET Connector for SharePoint from Bendsoft](http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/).

Generally SharePoint developers work in a virtual environment with SharePoint foundation installed creating their deployment packages locally.

Here is a good starting point if you want to set a virtual environment up for development. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint development needs ot be done on a system with SharePoint installed (forget about trying to remote, it never works well with SharePoint). You can install SharePoint on your PC/Laptop for development purposes - [How to Setup SharePoint Development Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)