# SharePoint server is not installed on this computer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013

I am new to SharePoint and I am using SharePoint 2013. I have installed the SharePoint server 2013 on one server and I want to create web parts from vs 2010. But my vs 2010 is present on different pc and I am getting the below error.

```
"A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer” in SharePoint 2013".
```

I have search on net and found some links. I have used the below link to create the web parts.

Link : http://sharepointcustomization.blogspot.in/2012/10/sharepoint-server-is-not-installed-on.html

So I have done the below chagnes to create a web parts.

1. I have Copy the whole registry keys to my local pc.
2. Copy the SharePoint dlls at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI from sharepoint server to local machine.
3. Copy the necessary sharepoint dlls to GAC by using below command.

   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC> gacutil.exe -i "c:\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll"
4. I have restared my pc and geting the same error as "A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer” in sharepoint 2013".

Can any one help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you need Visual Studio 2013 to develop SharePoint 2013 application.

Just one thing, if you are creating sharepoint apps you don't need to go through all steps in your link. Just go to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627.aspx) and download the napa development tools.

And as the other people said, it is NOT a good idea to develop farm solutions on a server where SharePoint is not installed. You are practically begging for trouble and to be honest, it's really hard to produce anything without debugging possibilited.

Just my five cents.

Comment: Hi @Joakim, thank-you for you answer. I know the concept of developing the apps and I am looking to develop the web parts. But more developer will work on vs2010 or vs 2012 to develop web parts simultaneously. So I have no way to working with one vs. So can you give me any ides?

Comment: I'm afraid you're going into a dead end. There is no known way today to make a "fake" installation of SharePoint 2013 to make it possible to develop on a non-server machine. I would install SharePoint on my pc or, preferrably, create a virtual machine. Oh, of course you have the option of going to the cloud, for example using cloudshare.com.

Comment: I am sorry to say As you said that "There is no known way today to make a face installation for sharepoint 2013...", But for the below link he is done the same thing on his local PC for SharePoint 2010. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66025/sharepoint-server-is-not-installed-on-this-computer. If this is possible, then why I am not? Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it is still better to have SharePoint installed locally for development purposes. I highly encourage you to just virtualize your development environment as cod

Comment: Thank-you for suggestion. But more developer will work on vs2010 to develop web parts simultaneously. So can you suggest how it will work with above one?

Comment: you can still integrate everything later on by using another virtual machine and set it up as an integration server. in this way developers can work individually and assigned tasks and later on integrate it in one server before finally deploying it to your production/qa server.

Comment: I don't want to setup any virtual machine. I have used the link : : http://sharepointcustomization.blogspot.in/2012/10/sharepoint-server-is-not-installed-on.html and he is done development with vs 2010. I have followed same but getting the error. Can you help me if there is any other way.

Comment: like I mentioned it will be hard developing web parts without having to  test it in SharePoint. so you either install SharePoint foundations so that you can hookup it up for debugging or setup a virtual machine. virtualization will also be better since if you will have a new team member for development you can just provide him/her the image everyone is using and you will all have the same configurations. like Joakim mentioned above, it is not advisable to dev without connecting to a sharepoint environment be it a test environment or not.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you need to have the visual studio together with the SharePoint Server installed (in your case, VS2010 must be installed in you server). It seems that you have the same problem as this guy, check out Eric Herlitz answer [SharePoint 2010 Development with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529917/sharepoint-2010-development-with-visual-studio) as the other answer only pertains you to installing either sharepoint in your pc or vs2010 in your sharepoint server. You would only be limited to using Rest API and/or ClientContext API or external connectors.

Comment: thank-you for answer. The guy has setup a virtual machine and done the development. But I don't want to set up any virtual machine. Can you help me?

Comment: if you wouldn't want any VM, try this to be able to install it in your pc.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28office.14%29.aspx

Comment: SharePoint Server is SharePoint Foundation with additional features. Therefore, all your SharePoint Foundation development skills can be used in SharePoint Server as well. The link you suggested is installing the SharePoint foundation and I am using windows 7 OS. This will not install the in windows 7 OS. I have already install SharePoint server 2013 on different pc and SharePoint designer 2013 on my local system, so why SharePoint foundation? Can you help if there is any other way or how I can do this?